# The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception with Oracle Database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I'm working with Entity Framework 6.1.3, ASP.NET Identity Entity Framework 2.2.1  and Oracle 12C in a ASP.NET MVC5 Project.

While I am trying to generate the database using Nuget command:-

```
Enable-Migrations
```

I am getting the below exception

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Configuration system failed to initialize --->
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Section or group
>   name 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' is already defined. Updates to
>   this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined.
>   (D:\Google\Projects\Others
>   Projects\Mvc5WithOracleDB\Mvc5WithOracleDB\tmp88C3.tmp line 10)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean
>   ignoreLocal)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors
>   schemaErrors)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String
>   configKey)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String
>   configKey)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_ConnectionStrings()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForAssembly(Assembly
>   assemblyHint, Type contextTypeHint)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForContext(Type
>   contextType)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..cctor()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..ctor()
>
>   at Mvc5WithOracleDB.Migrations.Configuration..ctor() in
>   D:\Google\Projects\Others
>   Projects\Mvc5WithOracleDB\Mvc5WithOracleDB\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line
>   7
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationsConfigurationFinder.FindMigrationsConfiguration(Type
>   contextType, String configurationTypeName, Func`2 noType, Func`3
>   multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run() 
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an
>   exception.

I checked previous questions in StackOverflow, and read the [Oracle Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/CodeFirst/index.html).But I can't solve this Problem.

My **Web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="User Id=C##aml;Password=aml123;Data Source=localhost/orcl"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>-->
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="localhost/orcl" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=C##aml;Password=aml123;Data Source=localhost/orcl" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

And my **ApplicatioDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("OracleDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("AML");
        modelBuilder
            .Properties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) &&
                        !p.Name.Contains("Id") &&
                        !p.Name.Contains("Provider"))
            .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(256));

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles").Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(c => c.UserName).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(c => c.Email).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

So my question is How to solve this error and if i am wrong the how to work with Entity Framework Code first with Oracle Database?

Comment: Check `machine.config` contents in `%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\%Version%\Config\machine.config`. If `oracle.manageddataaccess.client` element already exist there, you should know that you're declaring it twice as web.config joins machine.config during configuration runtime.

Comment: Then you may use only one of them (not both sections). I don't sure if you can delete the same section inside machine.config but you can try removing section with same name in web.config/configure machine.config to load Oracle provider without web.config.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thank's. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per **Tetsuya Yamamoto** Comment :

1. I go to `%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\%Version%\Config\machine.co‌​nfig` and find `oracle.manageddataaccess.client` and it's exist in `machine.co‌​nfig`.
2. so I removed

   `<section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />`

under `configSections` in `Web.config` in my project and problem is solved.

Thank's **Tetsuya Yamamoto**.